# Center aligning textbox in div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my text and textbox to center of the div. My main div is centered because of `margin:0 auto`. But I applied this to textbox and its not working.

```
<div class="CommentBox">
    Some text :
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.CommentBox {
    width:400px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: #A12A1E;
    color:White;
    margin:0 auto;
}


input[type="text"] {
    margin:10px auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/88pMc/

I have tried everything. As you can see the above code, I have added `margin:0 auto` but still my code is not working. The textbox is just not center aligning.

Can someone help me here. I am confused why this is not working as everywhere I have checked `margin:0 auto` is suggested for center aligning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a div inside the div named CommentBox. So your html can be as such:

```
<div class="CommentBox">
    <div>Some text:
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and you can add a CSS class to act upon this div as such:

```
.CommentBox > div {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:250px;
}
```

You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/L77Bf/

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 3):

### Best Solution: For horizontally center aligning

No need to add another div, in your existing css rule .CommentBox {} , just add `text-align:center;` and it will work.

JS Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LTatz/

If you need vertical center alignment also then you will have to do some extra work.

Answer (score 1):

Try 'display:block;'  This makes it behave like a block element (such as

).

[Further Explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Answer (score 1):

This Should do the Trick (Note the text-align and display properties):

```
.CommentBox {
    width:400px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: #A12A1E;
    color:White;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.CommentBox input[type="text"] {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And this is your updated Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/88pMc/20/

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to specify a fixed width for inner content, you can try this approach.

```
<div class='comment'>
  <span>
    <label>some text</label>
    <input type="text" />
  </span>
</div>
```

and the CSS would be:

```
.comment{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:400px;
  text-align:center;
}
.comment span{
  display:inline-block;
}
```